# How to get the web socket (WS) tab data programmatically?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, websocket, google-chrome-headless

I want to get information from a web socket running on a website. however since I am not aware of handshaking process I am unable to establish a successful connection to the websocket and retrieve the information being published on the websocket. I assume this falls on the website confidentiality and unless they provide me the documents it is highly unlikely I can get the data directly from the websocket (please correct me if I am wrong).

However since I can view the data from "WS" tab in network section of the chrome (developer mode). I was wondering if there is a way to replicate this programmatically using selenium or any headless browser and I get this information inside my program. my main objective is to get the information using C# however I am open to any other way to get this data.

[This is the sample picture of a WS](https://ibb.co/LgkYcL5)

I have also found this extension  "chrome.devtools.network" but I am not sure if it can do the thing I want. I am still searching any advice or help is highly appreciated

Comment: I dont want to do any testing, I just want to crawl the data and save it into my own database

Comment: This is a http request. Just send a http request and get the response. Why you want to use selenium here? Can't understand the question exactly. Please clarify it

Comment: normal http request does not work here. because as you know we have to do the handshake and send keep alive signal in order to keep getting information. the link below is the same example as the picture wss://data.tradingview.com/socket.io/websocket?from=chart%2F&date=2021_09_14-12_27

Comment: This link is just an example. I am do not want to get information from tradingview server but the concept is the same.

Comment: OK. I got it. The link you provide does not work. Please correct the link. Note that automation is the process of automating sequence. So if you should login to the site, open some url and then reach the graf, The process should be exactly the same sequence. Anyway provide a workable link in order to review the question

Comment: I just create an empty websoket chart, If you have any data for chart that I could import here would be better: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=WEBSOCKET

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I double check the link it is same as what i have shared earlier. however we can use the link you have provide with BTC symbol for example https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=BTC  if you inspect this under network tab you can find WS and there you can see the web socket

Comment: I could fetch websocket messages through logging preferences in Selenium for the second link you provide. Check source code, convert it to C#

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With new versions of Selenium webdrive (version 4 - It's beta version) you can create a devtool session of the driver

```
driver.getDevTools().createSession();
```

With wich you can send any devtool commands. You should create a web socket event and send the request through it. You can refer this [link](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/) for Network Domain Chrome DevTools Protocol.

Also, you can use logging preferences properties and intercept performance logs to fetch messages sent and received through websocket.

```
driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE);
```

I tried the last solution using Java ang get this result for requesting this [link](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=CRYPTOCAP%3ABTC)
[image]

Complete source code is provided [here](https://github.com/hanabizhani/SeleniumWebDriver-Tiny_projects/tree/main/GetWebsocketMessage)

Note that you should wait until the chrome driver quit. Then in console you'll see the sent and received messages